# Silverlight : Bind SelectedItem of DataGrid to Customized TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, datagrid, tabcontrol

Hello I have a dataGrid as follows

```
<sdk:DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding NodeCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Previously I had another DataGrid which was populated with the content of the SelectedItem from the above datagrid. Now I had to introduce a customized tab control which can add new tabs dynamically. The tab item must now display the content of the SelectedItem. I have a button(Add New) which adds a new tab item (duplicates the previous tab item) to the tab control.

```
<Button Content="Add New" Command="{Binding AddNewTemplateCommand}"/>

<templateTabs:BindableTabControl MyItemsSource="{Binding ModalityTemplates}">
<templateTabs:BindableTabControl.TabItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                       <tabView:ModalityTemplateView/>
                </DataTemplate>
<templateTabs:BindableTabControl.TabHeaderItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,2,2,2">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Button Height="16" Width="16" Margin="5,0,0,0" Padding="0" Command="{Binding DeleteTemplateCommand}" Content ="X" />
                    </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
</templateTabs:BindableTabControl.TabHeaderItemTemplate>
</templateTabs:BindableTabControl>
```

Currently I need to selected the item from the dataGrid and click the add new button to display the first default tab item. However I want that the first tab item be displayed as soon as an item from the dataGrid is selected.

Looking for a simple workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `BindableTabControl` is your code you can easily add a `DependencyProperty` to it that serves as a bindable source for the first (and only) item:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="NodeSelector" ... />
<templateTabs:BindableTabControl
    SingletonItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=NodeSelector}"
    MyItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModalityTemplates}">
    ...
</templateTabs:BindableTabControl>
```

Your tab control needs to react to any change of this new property:

```
public object SingletonItem
{
    get { return (object) GetValue(SingletonItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SingletonItemProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SingletonItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SingletonItem", typeof (object), typeof (BindableTabControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnSingletonItemChanged));

public static void OnSingletonItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((BindableTabControl) d).UpdateItems();
}

private void UpdateItems()
{
    //it is up to you to implement this method, so this is only a sketch
    //the null check for SingletonItem is missing too
    if (IsNullOrEmpty(MyItemsSource))
    {
        Items = Enumerable.FromSingleItem(SingletonItem);
    } else {
        Items = MyItemsSource;
    }
}
...
public static void OnMyItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.OldValue != null ) { RemoveItemsChangedEventHandlers( e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged ); }
    if ( MyItemsSource != null ) { AddItemsChangedEventHandlers( MyItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged ); }
    ((BindableTabControl) d).UpdateItems();
}

private void MyItemsSourceItemsChanged(...)
{
    ((BindableTabControl) d).UpdateItems();
}
```